# Error when trying to run an sql query in python

Tags: python, sql, ms-access

I have connected  to my access database using pyodbc.connect() but when i try to run a query i get this error message however I can't see the error in the code. I am running a query based on user input so i implemented nested if statements to run a query based on user input. The following is the code I have

```
  cursor = conn.cursor()
  # Runs a different query depending on the course and year
  if year == "Nat 5":
    if course == "SDD":
      sql = ('SELECT question, correct_answer FROM question_data WHERE question_type = SDD AND year_group = Nat 5')
    elif course == "CS":
      sql = ('SELECT question, correct_answer FROM question_data WHERE question_type = CS AND year_group = Nat 5')
    elif course == "WDD":
      sql = ('SELECT question, correct_answer FROM question_data WHERE question_type = WDD AND year_group = Nat 5')

  if year == "Higher":
    if course == "SDD":
      sql = ('SELECT question, correct_answer FROM question_data WHERE question_type = SDD AND year_group = Higher')
    elif course == "CS":
      sql = ('SELECT question, correct_answer FROM question_data WHERE question_type = CS AND year_group = Higher')
    elif course == "WDD":
      sql = ('SELECT question, correct_answer FROM question_data WHERE question_type = WDD AND year_group = Higher')


  cursor.execute(sql)
  rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

when i try to run this it gives me the following error message

```
TypeError: The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query.
```

I wanted to run a different query depending on user input earlier in the program but there seems to be an error in my implementing of the query of in the cursor.execute line. Anyone know exactly what the problem is?

*EDIT

I used f-string formatting and now have it in this format

```
  sql = (f'SELECT question, correct_answer FROM question_data WHERE question_type = {course} AND year_group = {year}')
```

However i now get the following error message

```
Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 3. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

I am told the error message refers to the following line of code.

```
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: Off-topic, but you can remove the if else statements using f-strings: `f'SELECT question, correct_answer FROM question_data WHERE question_type = {course} AND year_group = {year}'`

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal Thanks for the tip. Don't know how I never thought to use f-strings but I'll change that.

Comment: You should avoid using F-strings in SQL for literal values and instead use the well-known parameterization.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the best practice of [parameterization](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#executesql-parameters) supported with `pyodbc` and all other Python DB-APIs and languages beyond Python that run SQL queries. Additionally, doing so avoids the many `if` and `elif` needs.

Specifically, your first error may be due to a different code sample than what you posted where `sql` was not a scalar string but a tuple or list. Do note: the second argument of `cursor.execute` usually expects a tuple, list, or other iterable. Your latter error is due to missing quotes around the formatted Python variables in SQL statement. However, parameters avoids the need to use quotations or concatenate SQL statements.

```py
cursor = conn.cursor()
# Runs a different query depending on the course and year
sql = (
    'SELECT question, correct_answer '
    'FROM question_data '
    'WHERE question_type = ? AND year_group = ?'
)

cursor.execute(sql, [course, year])
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I implemented the exact code you suggested however i get the following error message. Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 3. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Comment: Carefully check if columns in `SELECT` or `WHERE` actual exist in table. Test by hard-coding the SQL with quotes aroud literals (which you do not do in posted code). Use double quotes around full string and single quotes around literals.

Comment: Does this raise any errors: `sql = "SELECT question, correct_answer FROM question_data WHERE question_type = 'SDD' AND year_group = 'Higher'"`?